# Regex Query to find the first tab before EOL

Tags: regex, editplus

I have a line that looks like this:

`$/Reporting/MSReportin gServices/Alle  gro/Ex  eXYZ.All    egro.Ss rs:`

The spaces are tabs, so here is what it actually looks like

`$/Reporting/MSReportin gServices/Alle{TAB}gro/Ex{TAB}eXYZ.All{TAB}egro.Ss{TAB}rs:`

I have to find the first tab in each line that starts with a `$` sign.

How do I do this using RegEx?

Comment: Find the first tab? Well, the first one **is** just a tab... :) Perhaps you want to find the index of the first tab? Or everything between `$` and the first tab?

Comment: @Bart K. I want to find the index of the first tab. I am using this in Editplus to edit a rather large file and remove tabs from only lines that start with a $ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to retrieve the first tab and replace it :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = qq!\$/Reporting/MSReportin\tgServices/Alle\tgro/Ex\teXYZ.All\tegro.Ss\trs:!;
$s =~ s/^(\$[^\t]*?)\t/$1HERE_IS_THE_FIRST_TAB/;
print '$1 = ',$1,"\n";
print '$s = ',$s,"\n";
```

Output:

```
$1 = $/Reporting/MSReportin
$s = $/Reporting/MSReportinHERE_IS_THE_FIRST_TABgServices/Alle  gro/Ex  eXYZ.All    egro.Ss rs:
```

But you have to be more specific about what's the meaning of `find the first tab`

Answer (score 2):

```
^\$(.*?)\t
```

Captures the text before the first tab. The length of the captured text plus one (for the dollar) tells you the index of the tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think this expression should do it: `^\$(/\w+/\w+)\t`